# recommend you something or recommend it to you

Tags: sentence-choice

I am going to make up two similar sentences.

(1) I strongly recommend you this new computer course.

(2) I strongly recommend this new computer course to you.

Which sentence sounds more natural?

Comment: Six of one, half a dozen of the other;)

Comment: I think that what @Rompey is saying is that both would be understood but to me #2 is more natural and would be the more common way of phrasing the sentence.

Comment: And I might say, "for you" instead of "to you."

Answer (score 2):

Grammatically, you don't recommend somebody to something, but you recommend something to somebody.

So the former sentence isn't grammatical, whereas  the latter is grammatical or natural.

Comment: What Khan said. Had the first sentence been, “I strongly recommend to you this new computer course” then it would not have been disqualified by not being grammatically correct (in the way the original was). But it would still tend to be inferior to the second which, to most native speakers, would usually (but no doubt there would be exceptions) sound more natural.